# Корректировка кода. Python(tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Какие блоки нижеприведённого кода нужно убрать, чтобы остался только первый тест(`test1`, "Приятно ли с вами общаться?"), второй(`test2`, "Благоразумны ли Вы") нужно убрать.

Просто если я тупо убираю все части, связанные со вторым тестом (кнопку его выбора, кортеж вопросов, ответы), у меня ломается первый тест, который как раз таки нужен.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

# Первым в кортеже идет название теста.

list_questions_1 = ("Приятно ли с Вами общаться ?", "1. Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?",
                    "2. Вы всегда можете найти тему для разговора даже с незнакомым человеком?",
                    "3. Вы всегда внимательно слушаете собеседника??", "4. Любите ли Вы давать советы?", "5. Если тема разговора Вам неинтересна, станете ли показыаать это собеседнику?",
                    "6. Раздражаетесь ли Вы, когда Вас не слушают?", "7. У Вас есть собственное мнение по любому вопросу?", "8. Если тема разговора Вам незнакома, станете ли её развивать?",
                    "9. Вы любите быть центром внимания?", "10. Есть ли хотя бы три предмета, по которым Вы обладаете достаточно прочными знаниями?",
                    "11. Вы хороший оратор?")
list_questions_2 = ("Благоразумны ли Вы?", "1. Выходите ли Вы из себя по малейшему поводу?", "2. Боитесь ли Вы разозлить человека, который физически сильнее Вас?",
"3. Начинаете ли Вы скандалить, чтобы на Вас обратили внимание?", "4. Любите ли Вы ездить на большой скорости, даже если это связано с риском для жизни?", "5. Увлекаетесь ли Вы лекарствами, когда заболеваете?",
                    "6. Пойдёте ли Вы на всё, чтобы получить то, что вам хочется?", "7. Любите ли Вы сидеть часами на солнце?", "8. Уверены ли  Вы, что когда-нибудь станете знаменитостью?",
                    "11. Любите ли Вы знать заранее, что  Вам подарят?")
test_suite = (list_questions_1, list_questions_2)

# Списки ответов
list_answers_1 = ("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes")
list_answers_2 = ("no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
tuple_answer = (list_answers_1, list_answers_2)

# По нему можно расчитывать результаты теста.
test_result = [0, 0]

ic = 0
i = 1
count = 0
result_text = " "

def result(answer, control, number, question, test):
    """ Функция переключения вопросов и сбор результатов"""
    global i
    global count
    global result_text
    global ic
    if answer == control[i - 1]:
        test_result[0] += 1
        count += 1
        ic = count + 0

    else:
        test_result[1] += 1
        count = ic

    if i < len(control):
        i += 1
        number.config(text=f"Вопрос номер {i}")
        question.config(text=f"{test[i]}")
    else:
        if (count>=0) and (count<=3):
            result_text = (f"Ваш реузльтат {count} баллов. Вы либо молчун, либо настолько общительны, что вас избегают. ")
            ic = 0
            count = 0
        elif (count>=4) and (count<=9):
            result_text = (f"Ваш реузльтат {count} баллов. Вы, может, и не слишком общительны, но почти всегда внимательны и приятны в беседе. ")
            ic = 0
            count = 0
        elif (count>=10) and (count<=11):
            result_text = (f"Ваш реузльтат {count} баллов. Вы, наверное один из самых приятных в общении людей. Вряд ли друзья могут без Вас обойтись.   ")
            count = 0
            ic = 0
        mb.showinfo(title="Результаты теста", message=result_text)
        i = 1



def test_fun(test_number):
    """ Окно теста"""

    global i

    test = test_suite[test_number - 1]
    control_answers = tuple_answer[test_number - 1]

    test_win = tk.Toplevel()
    test_win.title(f"Test {test[i - 1]}")
    test_win.geometry('575x575+100+100')

    question_number = tk.Label(test_win, text=f"Вопрос номер {i}", font="Arial 20", background="gray93",
                               justify="center")
    question_number.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    text_question = tk.Label(test_win, text=f"{test[i]}", font="Arial 10", background="gray93",
                             justify="center")
    text_question.place(relx=0, rely=0.4, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    yes = tk.Button(test_win, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16",
                    command=lambda: result('yes', control_answers, question_number, text_question, test))
    no = tk.Button(test_win, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16",
                   command=lambda: result('no', control_answers, question_number, text_question, test))

    yes.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
    no.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)



def main():
    """ Основное окно выбора теста"""

    len_test1 = len(list_questions_1) - 1
    len_test2 = len(list_questions_2) - 1

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Психологический тест")
    root.geometry('700x700+100+100')
    choose_lab = tk.Label(root, text="Выберите тест", width=30, height=1, font="Arial 20", background="gray93")
    choose_lab.place(x=100, y=1)
    test2_but = tk.Button(root, text=f"Приятно ли с Вами общаться? \n Всего {len_test1} вопросов", width=30, height=2,
                          font="Arial 20",
                          background="gray90", command=lambda: test_fun(1))
    test2_but.place(x=100, y=180)
    test3_but = tk.Button(root, text=f"Благоразумны ли Вы? \n Всего {len_test2} вопроса", width=30, height=2,
                          font="Arial 20", background="gray90",
                          command=lambda: test_fun(2))
    test3_but.place(x=100, y=380)
    root.mainloop()


main()
```

Comment: Разбираться лениво, но попробуйте для начала избавиться от `global` в функциях. Все аргументы должны в явном виде передаваться в функции, в противном случае это как-раз и приводит к "загадочному" их поведению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

# Первым в кортеже идет название теста.

list_questions_1 = ("Приятно ли с Вами общаться ?", "1. Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?",
                    "2. Вы всегда можете найти тему для разговора даже с незнакомым человеком?",
                    "3. Вы всегда внимательно слушаете собеседника??", "4. Любите ли Вы давать советы?", "5. Если тема разговора Вам неинтересна, станете ли показыаать это собеседнику?",
                    "6. Раздражаетесь ли Вы, когда Вас не слушают?", "7. У Вас есть собственное мнение по любому вопросу?", "8. Если тема разговора Вам незнакома, станете ли её развивать?",
                    "9. Вы любите быть центром внимания?", "10. Есть ли хотя бы три предмета, по которым Вы обладаете достаточно прочными знаниями?",
                    "11. Вы хороший оратор?")
list_questions_2 = ("Благоразумны ли Вы?", "1. Выходите ли Вы из себя по малейшему поводу?", "2. Боитесь ли Вы разозлить человека, который физически сильнее Вас?",
"3. Начинаете ли Вы скандалить, чтобы на Вас обратили внимание?", "4. Любите ли Вы ездить на большой скорости, даже если это связано с риском для жизни?", "5. Увлекаетесь ли Вы лекарствами, когда заболеваете?",
                    "6. Пойдёте ли Вы на всё, чтобы получить то, что вам хочется?", "7. Любите ли Вы сидеть часами на солнце?", "8. Уверены ли  Вы, что когда-нибудь станете знаменитостью?",
                    "11. Любите ли Вы знать заранее, что  Вам подарят?")

#test_suite = (list_questions_1, list_questions_2)
test_suite = (list_questions_1, )

# Списки ответов
list_answers_1 = ("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes")
list_answers_2 = ("no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
tuple_answer = (list_answers_1, list_answers_2)

# По нему можно расчитывать результаты теста.
test_result = [0, 0]

ic = 0
i = 1
count = 0
result_text = " "

# +++ -->  vvvvvvvv
def result(test_win, answer, control, number, question, test):
    """ Функция переключения вопросов и сбор результатов"""
    global i
    global count
    global result_text
    global ic
    if answer == control[i - 1]:
        test_result[0] += 1
        count += 1
        ic = count + 0

    else:
        test_result[1] += 1
        count = ic

    if i < len(control):
        i += 1
        number.config(text=f"Вопрос номер {i}")
        question.config(text=f"{test[i]}")
    else:
        if (count>=0) and (count<=3):
            result_text = (f"Ваш реузльтат {count} баллов. Вы либо молчун, либо настолько общительны, что вас избегают. ")
            ic = 0
            count = 0
        elif (count>=4) and (count<=9):
            result_text = (f"Ваш реузльтат {count} баллов. Вы, может, и не слишком общительны, но почти всегда внимательны и приятны в беседе. ")
            ic = 0
            count = 0
        elif (count>=10) and (count<=11):
            result_text = (f"Ваш реузльтат {count} баллов. Вы, наверное один из самых приятных в общении людей. Вряд ли друзья могут без Вас обойтись.   ")
            count = 0
            ic = 0
        mb.showinfo(title="Результаты теста", message=result_text)
        i = 1
# +++        
        test_win.destroy()                                              # +++   

def test_fun(test_number):
    """ Окно теста"""

    global i

    test = test_suite[test_number - 1]
    control_answers = tuple_answer[test_number - 1]

    test_win = tk.Toplevel()
    test_win.title(f"Test {test[i - 1]}")
    test_win.geometry('575x575+100+100')

    question_number = tk.Label(test_win, text=f"Вопрос номер {i}", font="Arial 20", background="gray93",
                               justify="center")
    question_number.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    text_question = tk.Label(test_win, text=f"{test[i]}", font="Arial 10", background="gray93",
                             justify="center")
    text_question.place(relx=0, rely=0.4, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    yes = tk.Button(test_win, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16",
# +++ ---------------------------------->  vvvvvvvv
                    command=lambda: result(test_win, 'yes', control_answers, question_number, text_question, test))
    no = tk.Button(test_win, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16",
# +++ --------------------------------->  vvvvvvvv    
                   command=lambda: result(test_win, 'no', control_answers, question_number, text_question, test))

    yes.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
    no.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)

def main():
    """ Основное окно выбора теста"""

    len_test1 = len(list_questions_1) - 1
    len_test2 = len(list_questions_2) - 1

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Психологический тест")
    root.geometry('700x600+100+100')
    choose_lab = tk.Label(root, text="Выберите тест", width=30, height=1, font="Arial 20", background="gray93")
    choose_lab.place(x=100, y=1)
    test2_but = tk.Button(root, text=f"Приятно ли с Вами общаться? \n Всего {len_test1} вопросов", width=30, height=2,
                          font="Arial 20",
                          background="gray90", command=lambda: test_fun(1))
    test2_but.place(x=100, y=180)
    
#    test3_but = tk.Button(root, text=f"Благоразумны ли Вы? \n Всего {len_test2} вопроса", width=30, height=2,
#                          font="Arial 20", background="gray90",
#                          command=lambda: test_fun(2))
#    test3_but.place(x=100, y=380)

    root.mainloop()


main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]